# How can I resolve TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'list' on Python (Pandas data frame)

Tags: python, dataframe

I've come across this issue and cannot seem to get past it. (I'm so new btw) Not sure how to format this, so I'll just try to explain. For reference, I'm practicing with World Educational Data on Kaggle [https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/nelgiriyewithana/world-educational-data/]

For context, I imported the dataset, used df.info() and noticed one of my columns of interest "Countries and areas" was an object type. Most of the other ones were int64. Not sure if it's an issue but I moved on.

Visual example of a few of my output:

```
 #   Column                                   Non-Null Count  Dtype 

 0   Countries and areas                      202 non-null    object 

 16  Completion_Rate_Upper_Secondary_Female   202 non-null    int64  

 28  Unemployment_Rate                        202 non-null    float64

dtypes: float64(6), int64(22), object(1)
```

I wanted to see the relationship between Completion_Rate_Upper_Secondary_Male and Unemployment_Rates using sns.lmplot. Have I done something wrong? Or is it something that I didn't do that's making this pop up?

I tried -

```
global_education='global_education.csv'
sns.lmplot(x='Completion_Rate_Upper_Secondary_Male',y='Unemployment_Rate',data=global_education)
```

and got -

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[46], line 2
      1 global_education='global_education.csv'
----> 2     sns.lmplot(x='Completion_Rate_Lower_Secondary_Male',y='Unemployment_Rate',data=global_education)

 File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\seaborn\regression.py:595, in lmplot(data, x, y, hue, col, row, palette, col_wrap, height, aspect, markers, sharex, sharey, hue_order, col_order, row_order, legend, legend_out, x_estimator, x_bins, x_ci, scatter, fit_reg, ci, n_boot, units, seed, order, logistic, lowess, robust, logx, x_partial, y_partial, truncate, x_jitter, y_jitter, scatter_kws, line_kws, facet_kws)
    593 need_cols = [x, y, hue, col, row, units, x_partial, y_partial]
    594 cols = np.unique([a for a in need_cols if a is not None]).tolist()
--> 595 data = data[cols]
    597 # Initialize the grid
    598 facets = FacetGrid(
    599     data, row=row, col=col, hue=hue,
    600     palette=palette,
   (...)
    603     **facet_kws,
    604 )

TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'list'
```

Comment: The *data* parameter to `lmplot` should be a dataframe, not a filename string.

Comment: I believe the `data=` argument is supposed to be a dataframe, not just a filename.

Comment: WOW, thank you so much guys, it worked!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're encountering typically occurs when Python expects an index for accessing an element of a string, list, or tuple but receives a different type, like a list or a string, instead.

In your case, the issue lies in how you're using sns.lmplot. The data parameter in sns.lmplot expects a DataFrame object, but you're passing a string ('global_education.csv'). This is why it's trying to index into the string with a list of column names, leading to the TypeError.

**Here's how you can resolve this:**

```
#1.Read the CSV File into a DataFrame: First, ensure that you have imported the pandas library and then read your CSV file into a pandas DataFrame. For example:

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# Load your dataset
global_education = pd.read_csv('global_education.csv')

#2.Use the DataFrame in sns.lmplot: After loading your data into a DataFrame, pass this DataFrame to the data argument in sns.lmplot.

sns.lmplot(x='Completion_Rate_Upper_Secondary_Male', 
               y='Unemployment_Rate', 
               data=global_education)
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer!! It worked when I tried it this way! :)